# How to prevent ASP.NET Chart Control images from being indexed?

Tags: search-engine, asp.net-charts

I have some pages on my public website that display charts generated by ASP.NET Chart controls.  How can I prevent them from being indexed by Google and other search engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the chart control you can setup the location that information is saved to, then simply setup a Robots.txt file to disallow indexing of content from that folder.

More information on Robots.txt to disallow image indexing can be found [here](http://boogiejack.com/html-help/html-help-image-indexing.html).

Comment: Maybe there's no other way, but doing this in a robots.txt doesn't make for a very cohesive development experience for our particular situation.  Currently, we don't do anything in our robots.txt.  It'd be nice if there was something equivalent to a rel="nofollow" for images.  That would make these chart snippets a lot more portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file. I believe most major search providers honors this.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) have some answers on the subject